# Posting data from iPhone application to php web page

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I am posting data from iphone application problem is that when i access the url using post from browser and pass www.apple.com then it shows result but when i pass from iphone code it does not return any thing in data as given below in code.

```
NSString * URL=@"www.apple.com";


NSLog(@"User Name entered is %@",URL);


NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"URL=%@",URL];


NSLog(@"post is %@",post);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/urlTest.php?"];


NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"%@",data);

data = [data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

Here is the PHP file Code

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}






$_URL=$_GET['URL'];




$html = file_get_contents_curl($_URL);


$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:

$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description' || $meta->getAttribute('name') == 'Description' )
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';



?>
```

This just return following in iphone

```
Title: <br/><br/>Description: <br/><br/>
2013-11-28 06:18:05.614 Hivelet[3861:60b] Title: <br/><br/>Description: <br/><br/>
```

Comment: @iDev what to check any error in code?

Comment: i'm not sure try with $_POST["test"]